# Sum if ONLY all the cells have a value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I need to sum 9 cells of data, each one on a separate sheet, but always in the same location. I only want a figure returned when all the cells have data, even if it's a 0. But, if one of the cells is blank I want a blank return.

I'm trying to get my head around, making it up actually, where the IFs and ISBLANK and SUMS would go. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
SUM(IF(ISBLANK(RANGEA,OR(RANGEB),0,ALLRANGES)))
```

Many thanks

Michael

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming the data is in A1 to A9:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9)<9,"",SUM(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9))
```

And yes, this will work for cells on different sheets, even files, just change the reference, make sure you change it in both parts of the formula though.

Comment: No horizontal scrollbar: nice! ;-)

Comment: Tried it and it works - off to put it to the real test now though. Wonderful use of COUNTA (I use that all the time but never thought of it like that!). Cheers.

Comment: Further suggestion: `COUNTA()` will count cells with numbers or text, `COUNT()` will only count cells with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The `IF` function works like this:

```
IF(TEST, DO_IF_TRUE, DO_IF_FALSE)
```

Unfortunately the `ISBLANK` function only works for one cell, so you have to nest IF statements like this:

```
=IF( ISBLANK(CELL1) , " " , IF( ISBLANK(CELL2), " ", IF( ISBLANK(CELL3), " ", SUM(RANGE) ) ) )
```

That will check if the first cell is blank.  If so it will print a blank space.  If not, it will test if the second cell is blank, print a blank space if so, and continue testing if not.  At the end, it prints the `SUM` if all are blank.

So, with 9 cells it would look like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",IF(ISBLANK(A4),"",IF(ISBLANK(A5),"",IF(ISBLANK(A6),"",IF(ISBLANK(A7),"",IF(ISBLANK(A8),"",IF(ISBLANK(A9),"",SUM(A1:A9))))))))))
```

Comment: It tells me I have entered to many arguments (9 Ifs in total) for this function.

Comment: I just tested this with 9 cells and it works fine.  The "too many arguments" indicates you have a stray comma or parenthesis somewhere.  I'll add an example that checks 9 cells to make it a little easier.

Comment: 7 nested ifs is the limit

Comment: It's probably a moot point given the other answers here but 7 nested functions is the limit in Excel 2003 - in Excel 2007 and later you can use up to 64

Answer (score 2):

In supplement to nnewton's answer above, you could reformat as `=IF(COUNTA(A1:A9)<9,"",SUM(A1:A9))` with the same result

Comment: Except that each cell is on a separate sheet...

Comment: You can use COUNTA with a "3d" reference, though, (to apply across a range of sheets), so assuming cell B3 on sheets 1 to 9 you can use this version of Diem's suggested formula `=IF(COUNTA(Sheet1:Sheet9!B3)<9,"",SUM(Sheet1:Sheet9!B3))`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it using this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(A3),ISBLANK(A4),ISBLANK(A5),ISBLANK(A6),ISBLANK(A7),ISBLANK(A8),ISBLANK(A9)),"",SUM(A1:A9))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array formula `{sum(a1:a10)*1}`. (Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the outside braces.)