# Sum only if any one of six cells have a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, worksheet-function

I would like a cell (total) to sum 6 other cells only if one of those 6 cells have a value. If none of the six have a value i do not want anything to appear.

Comment: What if 2 or more cells have values?

Comment: @Agrajag9 I would assume they are part of the *sum*.

Comment: possible duplicate [http://superuser.com/questions/252140/sum-if-only-all-the-cells-have-a-value](http://superuser.com/questions/252140/sum-if-only-all-the-cells-have-a-value)

Answer (score 5):

Blank if no cells contain data (i.e. all completely empty):

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A6),SUM(A1:A6), "")
```

Blank if no cells contain numbers (will also blank if they contain non-numerical data):

```
=IF(COUNT(A1:A6),SUM(A1:A6), "")
```

The difference is `COUNT` counts cells numbers only, while `COUNTA` counts cells that are not empty.

There's also a `COUNTBLANK` for ranges, which is what @alper.tekinalp attempted to do with `ISBLANK`. `ISBLANK` in Excel only supports checking a single cell, and will return `TRUE` for all ranges.

Comment: +1 @Bob I prefer the COUNT option but FYI it is possible to use ISBLANK with a range - but the result is an array and therefore formula needs to be "array entered", i.e.=IF(AND(ISBLANK(A1:A6)),"", SUM(A1:A6)) confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: I've never heard of Excel array formulae before ;) Though, in this case, I see no advantage to using `AND(ISBLANK())` over `COUNTBLANK()`.

Comment: No, I agree that your suggested approach is better, just showing that it is possible with ISBLANK........

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you may even have negative numbers at times, and this will not work if the inputs are not numbers.
Also am assuming you meant, you would like a total if there is a number in ANY of the 6 cells.

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A6)<>0,SUM(A1:A6),"")
```

or since positive and negatives would be entries but total zero perhaps

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:A6)<>0,SUM(A1:A6),"")
```

even a textual entry would be noticed but not add to a total. Not sure if that is acceptable either

Comment: But this will fail if the sum is actually 0, e.g. 4 + 2 + -4

Comment: good point -4+4 would both be in the cells, I adjusted answer

Comment: Argh, I can't do maths.. I meant 4 + -4.. Anyway, nice fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:F1)),VALUE(SUM(A1:F1)),'')
```

I tried this on open office. May work.

Comment: Two things: `ISBLANK()` in Excel only works on a single cell, and strings use `"`s, not `'`s.